# Winter / snow tires in Denmark for March

Tags: automobiles, denmark

I'm planning to rent a car in Denmark in late March.

Is it worth paying the extra for snow tires -- is there much snow on the roads by then?  FWIW, I live in the US mid-atlantic region and don't use winter tires at home.

Comment: I would strongly assume that if the weather conditions advise using winter tyres the rental company will supply you with a car that have them. They should be liable if they knowingly provide you with an inadequate car setup – unless they let you sign a waver at which point you can still request winter tyres. However, since I am not an expert on Danish law and did not yet rent a car in Denmark, I don’t feel qualified to post this as a full answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for winter tires. It's pretty far north but flat and close to sea level, so snow is actually not that common and March is fairly late in the season anyway.

I've never used any, even in mid winter.

Comment: The key factor for choosing winter tyres is outside temperature, not residual precipitation though.

Comment: Why? Winter tires are good for snow, but not great on ice. It's about the size of the contact area and the friction you get. No snow: no need for winter tires. Why would the temperature matter?

Comment: Reading up on Wikipedia I just found out that the old rule I had learnt in driving school (that it’s the temperature that matters and winter tyres provide more grip at lower temperatures on any surface due to their rubber mixture) has been refuted in experiments.